# Logging - changing level from INFO to DEBUG disables all logging messages

Tags: python, logging

I have only recently started using Python logging module. I've read docs and some guides, but still am confused as to why logging levels work the way they do.

I have a logger defined in the beginning of the script:

```py
import logging

log_file = f'test.log'
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
f_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file)
f_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
f_format = logging.Formatter(fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                             datefmt='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
f_handler.setFormatter(f_format)
logger.addHandler(f_handler)
logger.info('Initialising.')
```

Then throughout the code I have multiple calls to this logger - some `info`, some `exceptions` and `warnings` as well.

Yet, for some reason with the current setup I only get one `warning` message, if any, although I though that I should be getting all messages above and including `INFO` level.

To try and test it I switched the logger to `DEBUG` but I got an empty log as a result.

At the very least I expect to see the following `info` messages in the log:

```py
self.logger.info('Initialising.') #Right in the __init__ of the class
self.logger.info(f'Using {self.export_file} for export data.') #This one should always be printing unless script fails at the very start
self.logger.info(f'Using {self.model_file} model to predict values.') #Same with this one
self.logger.info('Encoding into a model completed successfully.') #This one as well if script completes successfully, which it normally does
```

I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: Please, provide [mcve] of the problem

Comment: The first code block already provides this. The message `self.logger.info('Initialising.')` never prints, even though it should be at `info` level and the file handler is set to `INFO` as well.

Comment: No it does not. `self` means it's a part of class definition (not present) and there is no example how you use that class. Provide [mcve] we can test and reproduce the problem, when we run it, without need to do anything else.

Comment: Apologies, changed the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from [`setLevel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel):

> When a logger is created, the level is set to NOTSET (which causes all messages to be processed when the logger is the root logger, or delegation to the parent when the logger is a non-root logger). Note that the **root logger is created with level WARNING**.

Also take a look at logging flow scheme [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-flow).

You should call `self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` to adjust root logger level.